# Phonegap 3.0 plugins not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using phonegap 3.2 and I'm unable to get my plugins to work.

I've followed all the directions on the site correctly I believe and haven't been able to get anywhere.

For example, trying to use the following

```
navigator.notification.vibrate(2500);
```

I get "undefined".

But if I just run

```
navigator.notification
```

I get the object back.

Answer (score 0):

First check your cordova_plugins.js

[image]
 if it is empty that is the reason, so after installing plugins you must **build your project** using  phonegap build ios /cordova build, that will solve your problem

Comment: My cordova_plugins.js file is populated with all the plugins i want. Still getting undefined when I run "navigator.notification.vibrate(100)"

Comment: giv ur device model, OS